# Why does Java robot pressing Enter not work?

Tags: java

I am able to get my text from a file, where it is saved as a string, into a JTextField. However, when I try to use the robot to hit enter so that it can process every command it will not work!

```
if (source.getText().equals("Load")) 
    {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(source);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            try{
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

                scan.useDelimiter(",");
                while(scan.hasNext())
                {
                    String open = scan.next();
                    panel1.command.setText(open);
                    panel1.loadFile();
                }
            }catch(Exception e1){
                System.out.println(e1);
            }



        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(source, "Loading a previous page",
                "Loading", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

that is for loading the file. Below is the code that makes the robot press enter.

```
public synchronized void loadFile()
{
        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630194/java-ignores-vk-enter-event-generated-by-robot

Comment: @zero01alpha unfortunately not :/ I changed my code so that the robot runs inside the while loop but I get a null pointer exception. The code is now  `panel1.robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)` with the appropriate key release.

Comment: Can you modify your code in a way that I can run it? Give me a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve