# How do make this part of the program run?

Tags: java

So I have a program that I am using to spam stuff (lol). Basically, it pastes whatever is copied to the clipboard and then spams it repeatedly. The thing is, when I run the code, it hits the ctrl and v keys but not enter. How do I get it to work?

```
public class spam {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            robot.keyPress(VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(VK_V);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            robot.keyPress(VK_ENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the content of `Robot` class ? and all other imports

Comment: You might need to release these keys as well after **pressing** them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630194/java-ignores-vk-enter-event-generated-by-robot

Comment: try: Comment line Thread.sleep() and use the robot.delay(2000);

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: you need to release your keys after pressing them. also checkout the robot.setAutoDelay() method!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because every tutorial mentions this.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Robot` class, you have to release the key as well, after pressing it. So, you would have to do something like this:

```
public class spam {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            robot.keyPress(VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyRelease(VK_V);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            robot.keyPress(VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(VK_ENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily find out more about this by going to the [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyRelease-int-) class in the [java api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), which has very well documented explanations about all of the methods in the java standard library.

Answer (score -1):

Using a second robot will solve the problem as well. Without the delay from Nikhil's answer above.

```java
public class spam {


public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        robot.keyPress(VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(VK_V);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        robot.keyPress(VK_ENTER);
        // 2nd Robot to my avail
        Robot okRobot = new Robot();

        // presses Enter
        okRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);    // press Enter
        okRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);  // release Enter


    }

}
}
```

Comment: This will keep both ctrl and v keys pressed until the program exits. I don't think this is a good idea. Also the delay is not a part of Nikhil's answer, but was in the original code. It's not needed to make Nikhil's answer work. My guess is it was put in by the OP in an effort to guess at  how to solve the issue they had.

Comment: yes, but the solution is the using of the second robot. 
Releasing the button is up to the OP.